# XCode, String encoding, cyrillic letters

Tags: ios, xcode, string, encoding, cyrillic

I have an issue with my iPhone application or rather Xcode.
I am currently trying to convert a string that i get from Google Translate to a string format that supports cyrillic letters. i tried many String Encodings so far, but none of them seem to work properly.

Here is my code so far:

```
NSString *word = @"hello";
NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/translate_a/t?client=t&text=%@&langpair=en|ru",word];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"http" host:@"translate.google.com" path:urlPath];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *data;
data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

And this is the result on the console:

```
[
    [
        [
            "ÐÒÉ×ÅÔ",
            "hello",
            "privet",
            ""
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "verb",
            [
                "ÚÄÏÒÏ×ÁÔØÓÑ",
                "Ú×ÁÔØ",
                "ÏËÌÉËÁÔØ"
            ],
            [
                [
                    "ÚÄÏÒÏ×ÁÔØÓÑ",
                    [
                        "greet",
                        "hello",
                        "salute",
                        "hullo",
                        "hallo",
                        "halloa"
                    ],
                    ,
                    0.0050860695
                ],
                [
                    "Ú×ÁÔØ",
                    [
                        "call",
                        "invite",
                        "shout",
                        "hail",
                        "hallo",
                        "hello"
                    ],
                    ,
                    2.7109536e-05
                ],
                [
                    "ÏËÌÉËÁÔØ",
                    [
                        "hail",
                        "holler",
                        "call",
                        "challenge",
                        "speak",
                        "hello"
                    ],
                    ,
                    2.7109536e-05
                ]
            ],
            "hello",
            2
        ],
        [
            "noun",
            [
                "ÐÒÉ×ÅÔÓÔ×ÉÅ",
                "ÐÒÉ×ÅÔÓÔ×ÅÎÎÙÊ ×ÏÚÇÌÁÓ",
                "×ÏÚÇÌÁÓ ÕÄÉ×ÌÅÎÉÑ"
            ],
            [
                [
                    "ÐÒÉ×ÅÔÓÔ×ÉÅ",
                    [
                        "greeting",
                        "welcome",
                        "salute",
                        "hail",
                        "salutation",
                        "hello"
                    ],
                    ,
                    0.0014801305
                ],
                [
                    "ÐÒÉ×ÅÔÓÔ×ÅÎÎÙÊ ×ÏÚÇÌÁÓ",
                    [
                        "hallo",
                        "halloa",
                        "viva",
                        "hello"
                    ],
                    ,
                    2.7536449e-05
                ],
                [
                    "×ÏÚÇÌÁÓ ÕÄÉ×ÌÅÎÉÑ",
                    [
                        "hallo",
                        "halloa",
                        "hello"
                    ],
                    ,
                    2.7109536e-05
                ]
            ],
            "hello",
            1
        ]
    ],
    "en",
    ,
    [
        [
            "ÐÒÉ×ÅÔ",
            [
                1
            ],
            true,
            false,
            1000,
            0,
            1,
            0
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "hello",
            1,
            [
                [
                    "ÐÒÉ×ÅÔ",
                    1000,
                    true,
                    false
                ],
                [
                    "úÄÒÁ×ÓÔ×ÕÊÔÅ",
                    0,
                    true,
                    false
                ],
                [
                    "Hello",
                    0,
                    true,
                    false
                ],
                [
                    "úÄÒÁ×ÓÔ×ÕÊ",
                    0,
                    true,
                    false
                ],
                [
                    "ÈÅÌÌÏ",
                    0,
                    true,
                    false
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    0,
                    5
                ]
            ],
            "hello"
        ]
    ],
    ,
    [
        ,
        "Hello!",
        [
            10
        ],
        ,
        true
    ],
    [

    ],
    2
]
```

So i hope you get my problem. I want the string to be "привет" and not "ÐÒÉ×ÅÔ".
When i tried to encode the data to other formats i usually get a "(null)" result to my string, like for NSUTF8StringEncoding for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"translate.google.com" returns UTF-8 with the following parameters:

```
NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/translate_a/t?client=t&text=%@&langpair=en|ru&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8",word];
```

Then

```
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks that worked just fine! But now i have another problem.
I want to split the string up into an array with the "componentsSeparatedByString:" but then it converts the letters again into weird signs. "привет" is then "\U043f\U0440\U0438\U0432\U0435\U0442" for example. What should i do now?

Comment: @Gustl007: That is only how the NSLog of an array prints non-ASCII characters, you need not worry about that. - But the response looks like JSON, so the proper way would be to use NSJSONSerialization (instead of componentsSeparatedByString). But the JSON seems to be invalid, so that does not work.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much!
And i don't really know much about JSON, but if you say it is invalid anyway i will not confuse myself with it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method on the data you're getting instead of `initWithData:encoding:`:

```
- (NSString*)decodeKOI8R:(NSData*)dataToDecode {
    CFStringRef aCFString = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, [dataToDecode bytes], kCFStringEncodingKOI8_R);
    NSString *decodedString = (__bridge NSString*)aCFString;
    return decodedString;
}
```